# Seeking Wiring Schematic or owners manual for my 1977 RV 4000 Watt Onan Generator model: 4NH-3CR/12014D

Tags: electrical, wiring, generator

I'm have trouble getting my Onan Generator that I acquired about a year and a half ago to run. It turns over and had an exceptionally weak spark. The coil seemed to be okay and the plugs and wires in good condition. I'm not very familiar with points ignition systems.

A friend of mine who is more experienced with older engines suggested I replaced the points module. I did and now I'm in no better of a situation however I noticed there are three condensers wired on this thing and I only expected to find one so I'm quite sure something is amiss. My searches on Google have been unsuccessful as far as finding anything for this model. The closest I've found is for the 6500 watt model and it's quite different.

Comment: When I contacted Onan for a set of points they gave me a part number and directed me to the closest dealer. I ordered the part for more than $50.00 and when it arrived it was not even close to what was required for my generator so after that experience I have a certain reluctance to ask them for anything as they seem to be incompetent.

Comment: Oddly enough I'm actually a year older than my generator and my RV, thank you very much! You provided exactly what I was looking for with laser point precision! I couldn't have asked for a more concise or complete answer. I was looking for a way to up vote your response but I was unable to locate an arrow that I was able to click on to provide you with your well deserved upvote!

Comment: The first one was a bullseye! Found exactly what I was hoping for and it answered all of my questions and even provided me with an added benefit. I'm not aware of how easily I can convert the output from 120 volts to 120/240 volts with almost no effort. This is a major benefit as I have a welder that runs on 240 and my generator should be able to handle the load should I find it necessary to operate it away from home!

Comment: Yeah, all the reports I have is that Onan parts supply is a nightmare.  Either unobtanium, or over the moon on price.

Answer (score 0):

I would start on the manufacturer's website. You may find product information and support resources.

https://www.cummins.com/generators/rv-generators